# Find both the velocity v and directed distance s after 1.7 seconds.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, projectile-motion

An object is moving along a coordinate line subject to the indicated acceleration a​ (in centimeters per second per​ second) with the initial velocity $v_0$ ​(in centimeters per​ second) and directed distance $s_0$ ​(in centimeters).  Find both the velocity $v$ and directed distance $s$ after 1.7 seconds.

$$\sqrt[3]{2t+1}$$
$v_0=0$, $s_0=10$

Comment: Uhh.. where exactly does that directed acceleration direct to?

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh sorry i had omitted that part. Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this,
acceleration=$\frac{dv}{dt}$

by integration, $$v-v_{0}=\frac{3}{8}(2t+1)^{\frac{4}{3}} - \frac{3}{8}$$
simply put t to get your answer, and further integrate $v$ to get your $s$.

EDIT: Missed that constant of integration.

Comment: by integrating acceleration, shouldn't i end up with what you have there + C?

Comment: Comment acknowledged.

Comment: how did you get 3/8? At this point i'm not sure what to plug in to get the right constant value

Comment: plugging in 0 for t and v give me -3/8 instead

Comment: U are right. Sorry again